# Call Ajax export function return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

When i call my function with a returning

```
export function getChampion(id, country) {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.24.2/data/${country}/champion.json`,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            idToChampion(data, id);
        }
    });
}

// Return the ChampionId
function idToChampion(data, theId) {
    let resultObject = search(theId, data);
    console.log(resultObject);
    return resultObject.id;
}

function search(key, inputArray) {
    inputArray = Object.values(inputArray.data)
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i].key === key) {
            return inputArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The function "getChampion" return undefined i don't understand why and how fix it. Thank by advance

Comment: you have no `return` statement in `getChampion` - therefore it returns `undefined` as per specification of the javascript language - ironically, your `idToChampion` functions returns a value that you don't even use

Comment: @JaromandaX  When i add a return in "getChampion" i have undefined too.

Comment: depends on where you added it ... `return $.ajax ....` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have tried in `"success: function(data) ... ` and after the ajax call

Comment: well, that's a clalback, so returning there does nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to return undefined, you can use a Promise to make it an async function.

```
export function getChampion(id, country) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.24.2/data/${country}/champion.json`,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

And then you can use

```
let data = await getChampion(id, country);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getChampion` function doesn't return any value.

Assuming you want to get champion data based on their id, you could try this function:

```js
async function getChampion({id, lang = "en_US"}) {
  const {data} = await $.getJSON(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.24.2/data/${lang}/champion.json`).promise()
  return data[id]
}
```

Here's how to call it:

```js
(async () => {
  console.log(await getChampion("Aatrox"))
  //=> { "title": "the Darkin Blade", "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...", ... }

  console.log(await getChampion("Ahri"))
  //=> { "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox", "blurb": "Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...", ... }
})()
```

You can also use the promise interface:

```js
getChampion("Aatrox").then(console.log)
//=> { "title": "the Darkin Blade", "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...", ... }

getChampion("Ahri").then(console.log)
//=> { "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox", "blurb": "Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...", ... }
```